# cannot click links contained within ajax response

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have some content returned via ajax, and that content contains some links, but if I click them nothing happens (they don't respond to the JS written for them). Then, If i refresh the page, the first time I click, it works, and then it doesn't again.

How can I make it work normally?

This is basically my ajax call:

```
$('a.add').click(function() {

        var data = {
        action: 'ADD_PROD'
        };

        // make the request
        $.get(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
            // $('#vru_div').html(data);
            $('div.left').html(response);    
        });
        // $('div.left').html('<img src=712.gif>');
        // alert('code');
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new links won't have any event handlers attached to them.

try using

```
  $('.left').on('click','a',function(){
      //your logic
  });
```